# Go math package has invalid result

Tags: math, go

I just ran this code on my pc:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "math"
)

func main() {
   const ali = 4e20
   fmt.Println(math.Sin(ali))
}
```

and got this result:

```
1.3471173831553043e+258
```

Why Sin result goes more than 1?

Python and some other languages have correct result

Comment: Very interesting. Are you sure `python` gives you the right answer? I tried: `math.sin(4e20)` and `math.sin(4e20 + 1)` and I get the same result: `-0.3298871424318473`. My feeling here is that with with floats that large, the precision is really low, and it is impossible to calculate `sin` accurately. I would almost think that `go` deliberately gave you large value on purpose, so you would know that something is wrong, but according to the source code: https://golang.org/src/math/sin.go?s=5085:5112#L164, it might have been on accident.

Comment: It appears to be a [known bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6794).  Not sure what the best work-around is.

Comment: Yeah @Akavall , it was right in python 2 and 3

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it's just an issue with the implementation, if the input is more than 2**49 it causes issues. Found a *really* old issue [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7110)

Comment: That bug has been closed as a duplicate of [this much more complete one](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6794).